# ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable adsbygoogle in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, adsense, astrojs

I have added Google Adsense to my website which uses Astro. Now when the website loads on Firefox the Display ads are not showing only the auto vignette ads and side rail ads are loading. On Safari and Chrome or any Chromium-based browser that display ad unit works properly.

On Firefox, I am encountering the following error:
[image: ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable adsbygoogle]

As mentioned, this error is encountered only on Firefox.

Here's `ads.js`:

```js
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
```

Following is the `posts.astro`

```js
<body>
    <!-- existing code... -->

    <article class="mt-20 mx-4 prose prose-md md:prose-lg font-inter md:mx-auto prose-p:leading-relaxed prose-headings:font-semibold prose-headings:tracking-tight prose-p:tracking-tight prose-a:font-sen prose-a:no-underline prose-a:text-[#6741d9] hover:prose-a:underline hover:prose-a:text-[#6741d9] mb-8">
        <script
          async
          src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
      <ins class="adsbygoogle my-10"
        style="display:block; text-align:center;"
        data-ad-layout="in-article"
        data-ad-format="fluid"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXX"></ins>
      <script src="../lib/ads.js"></script>
      <slot />
    </article>
  </body>
```